# R Identifing text string within column of dataframe

Tags: r

One column of my data frame has words and phrases.  I am trying to create a dummy variable for those fields within this column that have specific strings of text anywhere within.

For example:

- kite
- cars
- box kites
- model cars
- i like kites that fly
- cars of the world

  ```
   myvector<-c("kite","cars","box kites","model cars","i like kites that fly",
   "cars of the world")
  ```

I would want to identify all the fields with the string "kite"

I've tried a few things such as `any()`, `which()` and `%in%` but nothing has worked so far.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You didn't provided any reproducible example. But your answer will be grepl.

```
grepl("kite", df$words)
```

It will return a logical vector if the word is in the row.

If you want to match multiple words use logical or `|` inside the string to match

```
grepl("kite|cars|box kites", df$words)
```

Comment: cool, this works really well.  If I had 2 or more words would I just repeat this with another grepl()?  I tried searching 2 words with grepl(c("word1","word2"),df$words)  R didn't like that.  I also tried it with grepl("word1"|"word2",df$words) and grepl("word1"||"word2",df$words) but no luck. I can do multiple grepl()'s.  I don't have that many words but I thought I would ask.

Comment: create 1 dummy variable (1 or 0) but there are a few words to search on that would get a "1".  I can do grepl() for each word separately, sum the resulting vectors and ifelse a final vector if the sum is 0 then 0 else 1. Though if it could work in a single grepl() it's more efficient.

Comment: oh, the | is inside the quotes.  awesome!  Thanks

Comment: @willPhillips If you want to use a vector you could use `grepl(paste0(c("word1","word2"), collapse='|'), df$words)`