# partial grepl result in matching keywords with text strings for multiple columns

Tags: r, grepl

I have a list of diagnoses and I'd like to group them according to keywords. So, if one of the keywords in `ref[[1]]` is found in `mh$prb`, then `mh$group` gets a 1. The problem I'm running into with `grepl` is that some of my keywords are getting matched and others are not--even when they are present. I have the keywords in `ref` such that:

To assign the diagnosis group I did the following [using this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409437/5530234):

```
mh$group <- ifelse(grepl(ref[[1]], mh$prb), 1, 
                   ifelse(grepl(ref[[2]], mh$prb), 2,
                          ifelse(grepl(ref[[3]], mh$prb), 3,
                                 ifelse(grepl(ref[[4]], mh$prb), 4,
                                        ifelse(grepl(ref[[5]], mh$prb), 5,
                                               ifelse(grepl(ref[[6]], mh$prb), 6,
                                                      ifelse(grepl(ref[[7]], mh$prb), 7, 0
                                 )))))))
```

And, as you can see, I have a partial match where some keywords are getting tagged while others are not. For example, 'depression' is getting assigned while 'bipolar' is not.

```
> head(mh)
  prb                                             group
  <chr>                                           <dbl>
1 unspecified major depression  single episode     2.00
2 bipolar disorder  unspecified                    0   
3 unspecified major depression  recurrent episode  2.00
4 bipolar disorder unspecified                     0   
5 alcohol abuse unspecified                        7.00
6 cocaine dependence  uncomplicated                0
```

So I isolated for a test example. You can see the `t` df has `bipolar` and so does my `ref`.

```
> t <- filter(mh, prb == "bipolar disorder  unspecified")
> ref[[2]]
[1] "major| depression| depressive| bipolar| manic| mood| substance induced mood| substance induced mood| alcohol induced mood| alcohol induced mood| cocaine induced mood| cocaine induced mood| amphetamine induced mood| amphetamine induced mood| opioid induced mood| opioid induced mood| cannabis induced mood| cannabis induced mood| marijuana induced mood| marijuana induced mood| methamphetamine induced mood| methamphetamine induced mood| sedative| hypnotic anxiolytic induced mood"
> grepl("bipolar", t$prb)
[1] TRUE
> grepl("bipolar", ref[[2]])
[1] TRUE
> grepl(t$prb, ref[[2]])
[1] FALSE
> grepl(ref[[2]], t$prb)
[1] FALSE
```

So, "bipolar" is TRUE for both the `ref[[2]]` and `t$prb` individually, but is not TRUE when compared together. Where am I screwing up?

**EDIT:**

```
> dput(ref)
c("psychotic| schizophrenia| schizo| psychosis| delusional| delusion| paranoid| undifferentiated| disorganized| substance induced psychotic| substance induced psychosis| alcohol induced psychotic| alcohol induced psychosis| cocaine induced psychosis| cocaine induced psychotic| amphetamine induced psychosis| amphetamine induced psychotic| opioid induced psychosis| opioid induced psychotic| cannabis induced psychosis| cannabis induced psychotic| marijuana induced psychosis| marijuana induced psychotic| methamphetamine induced psychosis| methamphetamine induced psychotic| hallucinogen induced psychosis| hallucinogen induced psychotic| PCP induced psychosis| PCP induced psychotic| benzodiazepine induced psychosis| benzodiazepine induced psychotic| phencyclidine induced psychosis| phencyclidine induced psychotic", 
"major| depression| depressive| bipolar| manic| mood| substance induced mood| substance induced mood| alcohol induced mood| alcohol induced mood| cocaine induced mood| cocaine induced mood| amphetamine induced mood| amphetamine induced mood| opioid induced mood| opioid induced mood| cannabis induced mood| cannabis induced mood| marijuana induced mood| marijuana induced mood| methamphetamine induced mood| methamphetamine induced mood| sedative| hypnotic anxiolytic induced mood", 
"post| traumatic| PTSD| panic| intermittent| explosive", "borderline| schizoid| schizotypal| paranoid", 
"neuro| neurocognitive| cognitive| dementia| alzheimers| vascular", 
"autism| aspergers| spectrum| retardation| intellectual| disability", 
"alcohol| cannabis| marijuana| opioid| heroin| amphetamine| methamphetamine| cocaine| inhalant| hallucinogen| PCP| sedative| hypnotic| anxiolytic| benzodiazepine| Xanax| valium| phencyclidine| induced| substance induced| alcohol induced| cannabis induced| marijuana induced| opioid induced| heroin induced| amphetamine induced| methamphetamine induced| cocaine induced| inhalant induced| hallucinogen induced| PCP induced| sedative induced| hypnotic induced| anxiolytic induced| benzodiazepine induced| Xanax induced| valium induced| phencyclidine induced"
)

> dput(head(mh))
structure(list(prb = c("unspecified major depression  single episode", 
"bipolar disorder  unspecified", "unspecified major depression  recurrent episode", 
"bipolar disorder unspecified", "alcohol abuse unspecified", 
"cocaine dependence  uncomplicated")), .Names = "prb", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide `dput(ref)`, a `str` is insufficient for replication. (And `dput(head(mh))` would help, too.)

Comment: @r2evans my bad. will remember that for future. updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing the problem is the way your ref variable is defined.  When you have the **or** specified like "| bipolar", grep is looking for a space followed by the word "bipolar" thus you are missing all matches where the condition is the first word. 
To fix, try using "|bipolar" (will find the condition in compound words) or "|bipolar " (will find as separate words except the last word in the sentence).

Now to bulk fix the "ref" variable without manually removing all of the extra spaces, you can use grep.  | is a special character and needs to be double escaped.

```
ref<-gsub("\\| ", "\\|", ref)

#For example
ref[5]
```

> [1]
>   "neuro|neurocognitive|cognitive|dementia|alzheimers|vascular"

Now:

```
ifelse(grepl(ref[[1]], mh$prb), 1,....  )))))))
```

will produce:

```
[1] 2 2 2 2 7 7
```

Comment: That now makes so much sense: 'depression' had a space before it...Thank you very much.